# Maven, Git, Android and the Maven Release Plugin

Tags: java, android, git, maven, maven-2

Turning the the StackOverflow army for this one.  I really want to get a better build process in place  for our Android development team and am turning to Maven to help with library dependencies.

I am completely new to Maven and would really like to learn its power so I can host Maven repos for dependencies on GitHub.  Any great tutorials or read up that are recommend would be great.

Right now I have a test Android library push to GitHub and a Maven repo set up with it.  I'm trying to use the Maven Release Plugin to help automate the snapshot versioning and create tags on GitHub.  When I do the mvn release:prepare it fails with the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0:prepare (default-cli) on project DependencyTest: Unable to commit files
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The git-commit command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
```

I've found few questions on StackOverflow about this but none of the solutions fix my problem.  I have the SCM tags correctly set in the pom.xml file.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for all the help - this is all new to me but I am eager to learn!

Comment: Are You using windows or linux for development? This issue seems quite common using cygwin on windows or the git bash shell with the msysgit client. Usually it works using the git command from the windows prompt.

Comment: Running maven with the `-e` or even the `-X` option will give you more details and you may find some more info *why* the git commit failed.

Comment: Most important update the maven-release-plugin in your configuration. The version you are using is really out-of-date.

Comment: @khmarbaise what version should i be using? an example would be great!

Comment: i would try a newer version of the release plugin

Comment: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-release-plugin%22 (RElease 2.3.2).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and upgrading maven-release-pluginfrom 2.0 to 2.4.2 resolved it.